# MongoDB serialize Dictionary<MyEnum,object>

Tags: c#, mongodb, dictionary, serialization

I have model with some `Dictionary<MyEnum, object>`.
When I try to insert in mongoDB with the C# driver, an exception occure with the following message :

> When using DictionaryRepresentation.Document key values must serialize as strings.

Of course, I can add the attribute `[BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfArrays)]` and it work, but I want to be able to persist the enum as string.

```
public MyEnum {
  A,
  B
}

[BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.Document)]
public Dictionary<MyEnum, object> MyData { get; set; }
```

I want to have Something like that in mongo for different reasons.

```
{
   "MyData": {
      "B": "xxxx",
      "A": "xxxx"
   }
}
```

for a single enum, I just can use the `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]` attribute, but how to tell to the driver for a dictionary to serialize the enum key as string?

Comment: `public Dictionary<String, object> MyData { get; set; }` and then you pass `MyEnum.A.toString()` or use integer.

Comment: thanks, I already thought about it but I'm looking for a generic attribute that I can easilly add, but I don't know how I can do it or a convension pack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is too long for a comment but it refers to a comment.

This would require reflection to change type of this object while program is running. At first this is a very bad idea, At second this would be very slow.

I recommend you to use your dictionary implementation for this purpose or use an extension class:

```cs
public MyEnum {
  A,
  B
}

[BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.Document)]
public MyDictionary<String, MyEnum, object> MyData {get;set;}

public class MyDictionary<T1,T2,T3> : IDictionary{
    Dictionary<T1, T3> Dict = new Dictionary<T1, T3>();
    //implement dictionary...
}
```

```cs
public static class ExtentionsDictionary<T1,T2>{
    public static T2 Get(this IDictionary dict, MyEnum enum){
    var key = enum.ToString();
    return dict[key];
    }
    //Rest of the implementation
}
```

Comment: Interresting approach. I think I can adapt this easilly. thank you.

Comment: I found if you use [BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments)] you can use keys of any type so not bound by using strings as dictionary keys

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the dictionary serializer does not force the key to be a string type.
To get around this create a serializer of your own and select it using BsonSerializer attribute.

```
public class EnumDictionarySerializer<TKey, TDictionary> : DictionarySerializerBase<TDictionary> 
    where TKey : struct, Enum
    where TDictionary : class, IDictionary, new()
{
    public EnumDictionarySerializer():base(DictionaryRepresentation.Document, new EnumSerializer<TKey>(BsonType.String), new ObjectSerializer())
    {

    }

    protected override TDictionary CreateInstance()
    {
        return new TDictionary();
    }
}
```

Comment: I really could use an example of how to use.

Answer (score 5):

Building on the answer from @Hugh.walsh, I've created a flexible `DictionarySerializer` that can be configured with a serializer for the key and value.

```
public class DictionarySerializer<TDictionary, KeySerializer, ValueSerializer> : DictionarySerializerBase<TDictionary>
    where TDictionary : class, IDictionary, new()
    where KeySerializer : IBsonSerializer, new()
    where ValueSerializer : IBsonSerializer, new()
{
    public DictionarySerializer() : base(DictionaryRepresentation.Document, new KeySerializer(), new ValueSerializer())
    {
    }

    protected override TDictionary CreateInstance()
    {
        return new TDictionary();
    }
}

public class EnumStringSerializer<TEnum> : EnumSerializer<TEnum>
    where TEnum : struct
{
    public EnumStringSerializer() : base(BsonType.String) { }
}
```

Usage like this, where both key and value are enum types, but could be any type:

```
    [BsonSerializer(typeof(DictionarySerializer<
        Dictionary<MyEnumA, MyEnumB>, 
        EnumStringSerializer<MyEnumA>,
        EnumStringSerializer<MyEnumB>>))]
    public Dictionary<MyEnumA, MyEnumB> FeatureSettings { get; set; }
```

Comment: This nets me a `MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: Invalid element: 'FeatureToggleTypeEnum'.`. Any idea what could be missing? It sounds like it ignores the key's string serializer.

Comment: Adjust the types as needed. See my updated answer for pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did that – I just adjusted the type back for my comment, in order to fit your example :) I am getting this exception for a completely vanilla enumeration type (with manually defined constants).

Answer (score 0):

Building on Hugh.walsh answer, here I am trying to get a `Dictionary<MyEnum, string>` field to serialize...

```
[BsonSerializer(typeof(FiltersSerializer))]
public Dictionary<MyEnum, string> Filters { get; set; } = new ();

...

public class FiltersSerializer: DictionarySerializerBase<Dictionary<MyEnum, string>>
{
    public FiltersSerializer(): base(DictionaryRepresentation.Document, new EnumSerializer<MyEnum>(BsonType.String), new StringSerializer())
    {
    }
 
    protected override Dictionary<MyEnum, string> CreateInstance()
    {
        return new Dictionary<MyEnum, string>();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** But I have also just learned I can achieve the same result with this call at initialization...

```
 MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(
                    new EnumSerializer<MyEnum>(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.String));
```